# How to scale watermark with FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, size, resolution, watermark

I am using ffmpeg to change the resolution and type(mp4) of my videos but I also want to add a watermark on them, but the problem is that the size of the watermark is different in every video I upload (on some videos the watermark becomes small and on other videos become bigger).

Is there a way to add a watermark with a proportional scale to the videos so I don't have different sizes of the watermark?

Here's my code:

ffmpeg -i input_video.avi -i watermark.png -s 1280x720 -filter_complex overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h) output_video.mp4

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to send your watermark image through a [`scale2ref`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter before passing it to the `overlay` filter